# Perl, search string for occurrence of items of array

Tags: perl

For a file filter, I want to use an array of words, where lines are checked if they match any of the words.

I already have a rather straightforward approach to this (only the essential matching part):

```
# check if any of the @words is found in $term

@words= qw/one
two
three/;
$term= "too for the show";

# the following looks very C like

$size= @words;
$found= 0;

for ($i= 0; $i<$size && !$found; $i++) {
   $found|= $term=~ /$words[$i]/;
}

printf "found= %d\n", $found;
```

Having seen a lot of arcane syntax and solutions in Perl, I'm wondering if (or rather what) are more compact ways of writing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a regular expression from all the words and do just one match:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @words = qw( one two three );

my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, @words;

for my $term ('too for the show', 'five four three', 'bones') {
    my $found = $term =~ $regex;
    printf "found = %d\n", $found;
}
```

Matching `/\b(?:$regex)\b/` would prevent `bones` from matching `one`.

Comment: [`list2re` from Data::Munge](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge#list2re-LIST) does something very similar but also handles several edge cases.

Comment: +1 from OP. I like this one (it kind of shows the aracane ways of perl I was expecting).  But the one with the assembly fits my needs better.  thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble) to turn the search into one regex. That way each string only has to be scanned once making it more efficient for large numbers of lines.

Regexp::Assemble is preferable to doing it manually. It has a full API of things you might want to do with such a regex, it can handle edge cases, and it can intelligently compile into a more efficient regex.

For example, this program produces `(?^:\b(?:t(?:hree|wo)|one)\b)` which will result in less backtracking. This becomes VERY important as your word list increases in size. Recent versions of Perl, about 5.14 and up, will do this for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Regexp::Assemble;

# Wrap each word in \b (word break) so only the full word is
# matched. 'one' will match 'money' but '\bone\b' won't.
my @words= qw(
    \bone\b
    \btwo\b
    \bthree\b
);

# These lines simulate reading from a file.
my @lines = (
    "won for the money\n",
    "two for the show\n",
    "three to get ready\n",
    "now go cat go!\n"
);

# Assemble all the words into one regex.
my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new;
$ra->add(@words);

for my $line (@lines) {
    print $line if $line =~ $ra;
}
```

Also note the [`foreach` style loop to iterate over an array](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops), and the use of a [statement modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers).

Finally, I used `\b` to ensure that only the actual words are matched, not substrings like `money`.

Comment: Modern versions of perl will compile `one|two|three` into a trie internally, which does no backtracking.

Comment: @melpomene Yeah, it's worth a mention. Thanks. It's a very nice optimization, but now you have an efficiency dependency on the Perl version (I want to say [this became stable about 5.14](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perldelta.html#Regular-Expression-Bug-Fixes)?) And I'm not sure how complicated a regex it can handle. I wouldn't rely on it for something whose performance is critically dependent on regex optimization. And Regexp::Assemble solves so many other problems that it's still worth it.

Comment: I already require 5.10+ for other things so that's not much of a problem for me, but point taken.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I like this solution best, so you get the checkmark and +1 (I'll vote the others up too.)

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps an overly simplistic "translation" of your C like code into perl.

- Pro: It's compact
- Con: It's not very efficient (the other answers are a ton better here).

```
@words= qw/one
two
three/;
$term= "too for the show";

my @found = grep { $term =~ /$_/; } @words;

printf "found= %d\n", scalar @found;
```

Comment: If you just need a count, `my $count = grep { $term =~ /$_/ } @words` also works.

Comment: +1 from OP. I like this one (it kind of shows the aracane ways of perl I was expecting).  But the one with the assembly fits my needs better.  thanks for answering.